# How to modify the different values of the same file on 2 servers

Tags: ansible

The same file exists in the same directory of the two servers. I want to modify a certain value in this file separately, but the contents are different, how to modify

Server 1：

```
# /opt/center/conf/properties
kafka=test
```

Server 2：

```
# /opt/center/conf/properties
kafka=test
```

Now I want to change them to an incremental value (the number of `node-all`) and modify it to the following (if my `node-all` has 2)

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Server 1：

```
# /opt/center/conf/properties
kafka=node1
```

Server 2：

```
# /opt/center/conf/properties
kafka=node2
```

I tried this method, but the two files he modified are the same content, this is not what I want.

```
- name: modify properties
  replace:
    path=/opt/center/conf/properties
    regexp="^(kafka=+)[^\n]+$"
    replace="kafka=node{{index+1}}"
  loop: "{{groups['node-all']}}"
  run_once: true
  loop_control:
    index_var: index
```

result:

Server 1：

```
# /opt/center/conf/properties
kafka=node2
```

Server 2：

```
# /opt/center/conf/properties
kafka=node2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use the hostvars variables, avoiding arithmetic operations.

#### hosts file

```
[node-all]
node1 ansible_ssh_host=10.10.10.72 kafkaname="node01"
node2 ansible_ssh_host=10.10.10.73 kafkaname="node02"
```

#### Playbook becomes

```
- name: modify properties
  replace:
    path=/opt/center/conf/properties
    regexp="^(kafka=+)[^\n]+$"
    replace="kafka={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].kafkaname }}"
```

#### Update, if don't want to change in hosts file, add + 1 if needed

```
- name: modify properties
  replace:
    path=/opt/center/conf/properties
    regexp="^(kafka=+)[^\n]+$"
    replace="kafka=node{{ groups['all'].index(inventory_hostname) }}"
```

Comment: But I don't want to move something inside the hosts file, because I don't know how many he will have.

Comment: The second method solved the problem, thank you very much.